# routerLink not working in innerHTML with angular2&4.0.0+

Tags: angular, innerhtml, routerlink

I'm using:[angular-cli=1.0.0+ node=7.7.4+ angular=4.0.0+] 
in my html page i use code `<div [innerHTML]="htmlWrite"></div>`
ts: `htmlWrite='<a href="#" [routerLink]="/user/list"></a>'`
but when i use 'npm start' start my serve,in html i just see `<a href="#"></a>`,there is no link with '/user/list'.
I search answer much about this and I tried much times but still failed,could you tell me how to solve this ? by using NgComponentOutlet? or others? please tell me the detail.thanks. PS:angular2(4.0.0+)

Comment: share your code. remove href from <a>

Comment: I tried but no use

Comment: html:`div [innerHTML]="htmlWrite"></div>`   ts:`import {Component} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'home-sidebar',
    templateUrl: 'sidebar.html',
    styleUrls: ['sidebar.css']
})
export class SidebarComponent {
    constructor(){
       this.getMenuList(JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.getItem('menuList')));
    }
    htmlWrite:string = '';
    getMenuList(menuList:any):void{
        // some operate
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](https://www.intertech.com/Blog/angular-4-case-study-caution-about-binding-html-content-using-innerhtml/).

`[innerHTML]` does not support angular bindings and directives.

One solution though (depending on what you are trying to achieve) if you have a list of html links that you want to display conditionnaly would be to hardcode your html and use boolean to display them with an `*ngIf` on each div/link.

If your trying to grab html from a server try send some JSON instead and fill a pre-written html line with the variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following simple approach to **add route on your anchor tag**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60413820/7540573

it will **route the view without reloading the whole page**.

Answer (score -1):

write you code with simplicity.

```
<div> <a routerLink = "user/list"></a> </div>
```

Comment: it's just a example and I must write like this

Answer (score -1):

You don't need the href in your `<a>` tag when using the routerlink.

**Before**

```
<a href="#" routerLink="/user/list"></a>
```

**After**

```
<a routerLink="/user/list"></a>
```