# Angular4 routerLink inside innerHTML turned to lowercase

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a cmd where I get the content of the page from the server. Then content can include HTML and links. The problem is when I display this data the links don't work. When looking at page source it turns out that "routerLink" is transformed into "router link" and that's why it probably doesn't work. Here is my code:

My class, **notice that routerLink is in camelcase here**:

```
export class TwoComponent implements OnInit {
  data = '<a routerLink="/one">ONE</a>'; //this will actually come from backend server

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

And my html:

```
<div [innerHTML]="data | bypassSecurity"></div>
```

And when i load this page and look at the source **the routerLink is now in lowercase**:

```
<a routerlink="/one">ONE</a>
```

At first, i thought it's the bypassSecurity pipe that responsible but I checked the output of the pipe and routerLink was still in camel case there. So it seems like it happens somewhere else. Just in case here is my bypassSecurity pipe too:

```
export class BypassSecurityPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private sanitized: DomSanitizer) {}

  transform(value): any {
    return this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
  }
}
```

Any advice on where and why this lowercase transformation happens would be appreciated :)

Comment: Sorry, dont understand you, no difference compared to what?

Answer (score 36):

jcdsr's solution helped me a lot. I got this working by using it with `DomSanitizer`.

Here is how i did:

#### RouteTransformerDirective

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Directive({
  selector: '[routeTransformer]'
})
export class RouteTransformerDirective {

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private router: Router) { }

  @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
  public onClick(event) {
    if (event.target.tagName === 'A') {
      this.router.navigate([event.target.getAttribute('href')]);
      event.preventDefault();
    } else {
      return;
    }
  }

};
```

#### Component

```
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';

public html: SafeHtml;

constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    this.html = sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml('<a href="/something">Link</a>');
}
```

#### Template

```
<div [innerHtml]="html" routeTransformer></div>
```

Comment: There is a problem if URL contains a fragment. In this cause, you might want to do something like `const hrefAtt = event.target.getAttribute('href');
      if(hrefAtt.startsWith('/')) {
        let url;
        let fragment;
        if(hrefAtt.includes('#')) {
          url = hrefAtt.substr(0,hrefAtt.indexOf('#'));
          fragment = hrefAtt.substr(hrefAtt.indexOf('#') + 1);
        }
        else {
          url = hrefAtt;
        }
        this.router.navigate([url], { fragment: fragment });
        event.preventDefault();
    }` inside `if (event.target.tagName === 'A') {`

Comment: Thank you very much @Efe this is working very well.. Just to note private el: ElementRef dependency is not needed.

Comment: We can use a custom safe-html pipe with this implementation.
`import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
  name: 'safeHtml'
})
export class SafeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(protected sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  transform(value: any): SafeHtml {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
  }

}`
Template -- `<span [innerHtml]="notification.message | safeHtml" appRouteTransfomer></span>`

Comment: Lovely solution and it works for me nicely. (**Angular 11.2.4**)

**NB:** Please follow Anguler  Style suggestion for directive name selection [Anguler directive nameing style link](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#style-02-08)

Answer (score 14):

This is my solution, you only need to use html5 attributes.

on template:

```
        <div [innerHtml]="testHtml" (click)="getRoute($event)"></div>
```

in component:

```
        import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
        import { Router } from '@angular/router';

        @Component({
          selector: 'app',
          templateUrl: './app.component.html',
          styleUrls:['./app.component.css'],

        })

        export class oneComponent implements OnInit {

            testHtml: any;

            constructor( private router: Router,) {}

            this.testHtml=`
            <br>
            ------- <span data-link="/page 1">Page 1</span> ------- 
            <br>
            ------- <a data-link="/page 2">Page 2</a> ------- 
            <br>
            text -- `;


            getRoute(event) {
                var goRoute = event.target.getAttribute('data-link')
                alert(goRoute);
                this.router.navigate([goRoute]);
            }
        }
```

or as directive,

```
        import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
        import { Router } from '@angular/router';

        @Directive({     
            selector: '[routeDirective]'
        })

        export class routeDirective {

          constructor(private el: ElementRef, private router: Router) { }

            @HostListener('click', ['$event.target']) onClick($event){
                console.info('clicked: ' + $event.getAttribute('data-link'));
                var goRoute = $event.getAttribute('data-link');
                this.router.navigate([goRoute]);

            }


        }
```

on template as directive:

```
        <div [innerHtml]="testHtml" routeDirective></div>
```

disadvantages:

Search engines are fine with "a tag" with no attributes. They won't see it as a link and they won't try to pass link juice to it - SEO.

Comment: you can also use pipes if you want to, like:  

<div [innerHtml]="testHtml | safeHtml: 'html':'url'" (click)="getRoute($event)"></div>

Comment: Very good solution to get links working without too much trouble. Thanks!

Comment: @HostListener('click', ['$event.target']) onClick($event){ Working for me thanks!

Comment: To get de SEO working, just add the href attributes with links, but disable them in your `getRoute(event)` method by using `event.preventDefault();`

Answer (score 1):

You can use following simple approach to **add route on your anchor tag**

**In .ts**

```
let baseUrl = 'http://localhost/'
let body = `<a href="http://localhost/discussion/details/">route detail</a> and 2nd <a href="http://localhost/discussion/list">route list</a>`
body = body.replace(/href/g, "value");
body = body.replace(new RegExp(baseUrl, 'g'), "");
```

**In .html**

```
<div (click)='changeRoute($event)' [innerHTML]="body"></div>
```

**In .ts after click event**

```
changeRoute(value){
  let myRoute=value.target.attributes.value.value;
  this.router.navigate([myRoute]);
 }
```

it will **route the view without reloading the whole page**.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try others routerLink syntax to see if the interpreter will act differently ?

```
<a [routerLink]="javascript code here that return a string or an array"> </a>
```

instead of your

```
<a routerlink="/one">ONE</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a very handy solution for having `routerLink` inside `innerHTML` using Angular Elements:

1. Add Custom Elements 
   `ng add @angular/elements`
2. Create Component as wished with an input for "href"
3. in the template use it like this:

```html
<a [routerLink]="href"><ng-content></ng-content></a>
```

4. Register Custom Element inside the prefered Component where you want to add the routerLink in the innerHTML
5. in the innerHTML string use your custom element instead of the `<a>` tag like this

```html
<your-custom-element href="/your/link">THE LINK TITLE</your-custom-element>
```

this way you have full control of the router link and still using innerHTML with content from an external (trusted) source.

Answer (score -4):

I don't really know what are you trying to achieve here, but you shouldn't get the whole piece of code from the backend. Instead just receive the value 'one' and use interpolation on the client side to generate `<a routerLink="/one">ONE</a>`:

In the template:

```
<a routerLink="value">{{value}}</a>
```

Comment: Its a CMS. User has a wysiwyg editor and can design a whole section of the page including html and links.

Comment: It is the default behaviour of the DOM. There is no real solution to that since it will always be transformed to lowercase. What you can do is generate a (click)="method(value)" and then handle that router navigation in that method with the value argument as the target route.

Comment: just try my solution above

Answer (score -4):

You should return `<a href="/one">ONE</a>` instead `<a routerLink="/one">ONE</a>` from server.

I have tried this and this is working for me.

Comment: href reload the app, I'm looking some solutions using routerLink in a tag into innerhtml

Comment: your solution doesn't work, routerLink after complie is render as 'routerlink' with "L" lowercase