# Angular 4+ : is it possible to evaluate a string input to a template as HTML?

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular-template, angular-pipe

Is there a way to evaluate strings passed into a component's template as HTML?

I am passing this:

```
export const BARS: Blurb = {
  title: "Bars",
  description: "blah blah blah. <a routerLink='/barcades'>Barcades</a>"
}
```

into this:

```
<h3>{{blurb.title}}</h3>
<p>{{blurb.description}}</p>
```

It is currently printing `<a routerLink='/barcades'>Barcades</a>` literally, without evaluating it.

As a background, I am making a travel blog.  All of my pages have the same structure: a bunch of sections of text with headings.  In order to avoid code duplication, I created data classes based on a model class like [these](https://stackblitz.com/angular/jdvddpgbkgv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhero.ts).

Basically, I created JSONs of all of the literary content for my website, then passed them into multiple instances of a common component.  This seemed like a great idea at the time, but now I want to add links(preferably even routerLinks).  Is this possible?  Maybe using pipes?  And is this even an acceptable strategy?  I'm curious to know if there's a standard approach in Angular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is [innerHTML](https://alligator.io/angular/innerhtml-binding-angular/) property. Something like this: `<div [innerHTML]="yourStringObject"> ....`

You might also need to sanitize it first, look at the thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43452220/sanitize-innerhtml-from-an-angular-directive).

Comment: Thanks!  This works immediately for regular `href` links.  Still trying to figure out if it will work with routerLinks.

Comment: what get's rendered in your HTML file? Is it possible you have [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44613069/angular4-routerlink-inside-innerhtml-turned-to-lowercase)?

Comment: Looking into it.  I'm not sure that's my problem though.  When I view the page in my browser, the routerLink is completely removed, not just in lowercase.