# How can i bind a anchor tag in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

in my angular application, i am trying to bind a string to a div using angular innerHTML,
Here is the string

```
sample = "<a routerLink='/tags/name/'>Test</a>  smod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam";
```

here is the html page

```
<p [innerHTML]="sample"></p>
```

Now my problem is that the anchor tag is now working, it only displays the `Test` but i cant click it to navigate to the other page, how can i make it to work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44613069/angular4-routerlink-inside-innerhtml-turned-to-lowercase/60413820#60413820

Answer (score 0):

The `routerLink` selector is an Angular specific property, which means it probably won't work when it's bound as raw HTML in an element.

You're better off doing something like this:

### HTML

```html
<p>
  <a [routerLink]="myLink">{{myLinkLabel}}</a> 
  {{myLabel}}
</p>
```

### Typescript

```
myLink = ['/something/here'] // Links have to be arrays
myLinkLabel = 'Test'
myLabel = 'smod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam'
```

Comment: But that's the value i am getting from my database

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach is to sanitize the html and use a directive to handle the click event.

Look at that answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49006667/5264995.